# How do I prove the following equality properly?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In a linear algebra assessment, I had to show that $W$ is subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ for:

$$W = \left \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3} \mid \frac{x}{3} = y = 2z \right \}$$

I showed that it is a subspace but didn't get all the marks because my tutor thinks I didn't prove things properly.

I showed that the zero vector is in $W$, so it is not empty. The I showed that it is closed under addition, and here is where things went wrong.

This is what I did:

Let $\frac{a_1}{3}= {b_1}= {2c_1} \in W$ and $\frac{a_2}{3}= {b_2}= {2c_2} \in W$.

Since $\frac{a_1}{3}= {b_1}= {2c_1}$ and $\frac{a_2}{3}= {b_2}= {2c_2}$, then $\frac{a_1}{3}+\frac{a_2}{3}= {b_1} + {b_2}= {2c_1} + {2c_2} \in W \therefore W\text{ is closed under vector addition}.$

Then I proved that it is closed under scalar multiplication.

Is my tutor being very pedantic or is there a more proper way to show this? It seems very obvious so I don't know how I can make it any clearer.

Comment: The problems lies with the fact that $a \in W$. Rather write for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $(a,b,c) \in W$... Perhaps a tad pedantic, but precision is also important.

Answer (score 3):

You are not actually giving elements in $W$. Vectors in $W$ have the form $(a, b, c)$ not $\left(\frac{a}{3}=b=2c\right)$, the components of the vector merely satisfy the equation that you are given.

You are correct in how to test for linearity (the condition that $W$ is a subspace of $V$), but you are not listing proper vectors in $W$.

Hope this helped!

Comment: So I need to give something like $(12,4,2)$ and $(3,1,\frac{1}{2})$?

Comment: Yes, except they should be abstract variables. So something like $\left(a_1,b_1,c_1\right)$ and $\left(a_2,b_2,c_2\right)$.

Comment: After I give the abstract variables, how do I prove the equality? If I recall correctly, I think I gave abstract variables for vectors in $W$ as you said but my tutor was mainly unhappy with the equality. Is it possible to make it any clearer?

Comment: Given the two vectors I gave above, you should show that $\left(a_1+a_2,b_1+b_2,c_1+c_2\right)\in W$. You sort of were there, but didn't really specify the actual vectors nor the sum of the two vectors (which is also in $\mathbb{R}^3$).

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, thank you. Hopefully I don't make the same mistakes in the finals :)